# change value and run function on click

Tags: jquery, highcharts

```
function ShowChart() {
    var fromDate = $("#fromdate").val().replace(",", "");
    var toDate = $("#todate").val().replace(",", "");
    var chartType = 'Customers'; // Revenue,Refunds,Customers,Purchases
    var chartURL = "<?php echo base_url() . 'merchant/GetChartData/'; ?>";
    chartURL += chartType + "/" + fromDate + "/" + toDate + "/";
}
// run it
ShowChart();
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#Revenue">Revenue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Refunds">Refunds</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Customers">Customers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Purchases">Purchases</a></li>
</ul>
```

This the chart setup I have where I can show chart by changing the `chartType` manually, but I want to automate this so clicking on the link will update the chart.

I know href values can be read and stored with `var str = this.href.split("#")[1];` but I'm not sure how to "change" the value of `chartType` and also "run" the function on each click?

Comment: You can dynamically chart type by update function http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.click()` to attach the ShowChart function to the click event of each of the `<a>` tags using the `.tabs a` selector. Then simply set `chartType` to your `split` code.

```
function ShowChart() {
    var fromDate = $("#fromdate").val().replace(",", "");
    var toDate = $("#todate").val().replace(",", "");
    var chartType = this.href.split("#")[1]; // Revenue,Refunds,Customers,Purchases
    var chartURL = "<?php echo base_url() . 'merchant/GetChartData/'; ?>";
    chartURL += chartType + "/" + fromDate + "/" + toDate + "/";
}

// Attach event to every a under .tab    
$('.tabs a').click(ShowChart);
```